# unable to set i2c speed for raspberry pi 3

Tags: i2c

I found several tutorials online on how to change the I2C speed on RPi3. They all boil down to [this one](https://gist.github.com/ribasco/c22ab6b791e681800df47dd0a46c7c3a). The script does work and I do read a 400000 value. However when I look at the scope my frequency is about 246KHz. I also tried setting it to 100000 and got back a frequency on the scope equal to 62KHz. What's going on? Should I be using different values?

Comment: so, fairly consistent - you say "about 246K" and "equal to 62K" - so, is 248K (i.e. 62 * 4) *about 246K*?

Comment: Why do you care? `SCL` is **NOT** a continuous clock.

Comment: @Milliways The driver doesn't seem to sample input correctly from my slave device which runs at 100KHz. I did try changing the value but the error still persists. It looks like there is a mismatch between hardware and software.